# How to use tokens with actions module?

Tags: 8, tokens, actions

I'm trying to use core `Actions` module to send email after new comment has been inserted. I'm doing it with `Action::load('<my_mail_action>')->execute([$entity]);` executed with `function hook_comment_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)`. This works fine. But I don't know, which tokens can I use in email body. I tried to use `[comment:entity]`,etc, but they aren't replaced. I'm using Drupal 8.2

Comment: Can you post your complete function/action? Chances are that you need to call the token replacement manually.

Comment: I'm using `Send mail` action supplied with the module. Is says it supports tokens depending on the context it's executed in.